# Making a timer work with a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, timer

I'm making a game in java. I want to **update the speed of an object moving down** each time the **score** ("counter") is added once. I tried using if statements, but there's no possible way I can list from 1-X amount of scores for my code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
if (completed > 0) {
        counter += completed;
if (counter == 1) {
               t1.stop();
               t1 = new Timer(250, ap);
               t1.start();
           }
           if (counter == 2) {
               t1.stop();
               t1 = new Timer(200, ap);
               t1.start();
           }
           if (counter == 3) {
               t1.stop();
               t1 = new Timer(10, ap);
               t1.start();
           }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the object to go faster each time the score goes up?

Comment: Just create a function, increaseTime(int:i), and it takes a class variable, t1, stops it, then starts with with a new Timer(i*100)

Comment: @Aggressor , I don't think Timer(i*100) is possible because that would make the object go SLOWER. Essentially, I want the number in new Timer(#, ap) to be lower AS counter++

Comment: Im still not clear on what you're asking. Can be you be more specific? Give me an example in english. E.g. Joe is walking at 1 mile an hour. He ate a cherry, and he is now walking at 2 miles an hour.

Comment: Joe walks 1 mile an hour. He eats a cherry, and now he walks 1 mile in half an hour. He eats another cherry, and how he walks 1 mile in 15 minutes... etc.

Comment: @Aggressor ^ see comment above

Comment: I posted an answer already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function decreaseTime(score:Int)
{
  var time:float = 500 * (1/score)
  //ap from your other code
  _t1.stop(); //<---- member variable
  _t1 = new Timer(time, ap);
  _t1.start();
}
```

The higher the score the faster the timer will go

The point is you need to decide how much your time speeds up. You could also do something like each point decreases time by 10, in which case you'd have

```
var time:float = 500 - (score*10)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `Timer`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (completed > 0) {
    counter += completed;
    if (counter == 1) {
           t1.stop();
           t1 = new Timer(250, ap);
           t1.start();
       }
       if (counter == 2) {
           t1.stop();
           t1 = new Timer(200, ap);
           t1.start();
       }
       if (counter == 3) {
           t1.stop();
           t1 = new Timer(10, ap);
           t1.start();
       }

    }
}, delay, period);
```

Where `delay` is the milliseconds before the timer should run the task for the first time, and `period` is the delay between executions.

Comment: If I delay, won't that make the timer go slower? I want the timer # to decrease while counter increases.